# How to startup the Oracle Database 19c without using parameter pfile?

Tags: oracle

Dears,

I am starting my Oracle database using the following startup code. Can you help me how to startup without the parameter.

```
SQL> startup pfile='E:\app\oracle\admin\prod\pfile\init.ora.572021131644';
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 2382361384 bytes
Fixed Size                  9270056 bytes
Variable Size             520093696 bytes
Database Buffers         1845493760 bytes
Redo Buffers                7503872 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
```

But how can I start as below

```
SQL> startup
```

Because it showing the following error

```
 startup
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file 'E:\APP\WINDOWS.X64_193000_DB_HOME\DATABASE\INITPROD.ORA'
```

Comment: Check settings for your ORACLE_HOME in windows environment properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To startup a database without specifying anything, you have 2 options.

The first way is to copy your current PFILE to `%ORACLE_HOME%\database\` and rename the file into `INIT%ORACLE_SID%.ORA`. For example, `INITPROD.ORA`. The database will choose it to startup, if there's no default SPFILE.

In which, %ORACLE_HOME% is the Oracle product home path, %ORACLE_SID% is the instance name. In your case, %ORACLE_HOME% is `E:\APP\WINDOWS.X64_193000_DB_HOME` and %ORACLE_SID% is `PROD`, according to your error message.

The second way is to create a SPFILE for your default server parameter file.

```
SQL> create spfile from pfile='E:\app\oracle\admin\prod\pfile\init.ora.572021131644';

File created.
```

After that, SPFILE is created with the path `%ORACLE_HOME\database\SPFILE%ORACLE_SID%`.

The thing is, Oracle searches for proper file to open the database by the following order:

1. SPFILE with ORACLE_SID, e.g. `SPFILEPROD.ORA`.
2. SPFILE without ORACLE_SID, e.g. `SPFILE.ORA`.
3. PFILE with ORACLE_SID, e.g. `INITPROD.ORA`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that starting an Oracle database from a **PFILE** is *unusual*.
Oracle databases usually *expect* to be started from an **SPFILE**.

Start the database (with the pfile parameter), then execute the command
`create spfile from pfile;`

Your database will now [always] start from the SPFILE unless *explicitly* told to do otherwise.

Comment: It is showing the following error  create spfile from pfile;
 create spfile from pfile
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file
'E:\APP\WINDOWS.X64_193000_DB_HOME\DATABASE\INITPROD.ORA'

Comment: I have created spfile as below and works now  create spfile from pfile='E:\app\oracle\admin\prod\pfile\init.ora.572021131644';